# Issue with in string operator in a module in python

Tags: python, string

When I use the operator `in` to compare strings in my program it works great but if I call it in a module I created it doesn't seem to work. I know I am making some error but not certain what it is, can anyone help?

Here is my code:

Module:

```
def checkRoots(wordChecked, rootList):
    numRoots = len(rootList);
    numTypeRoots = createList(numRoots);
    for z in range(0, numRoots):
        root = rootList[z];
        rootThere = root in word;
        if rootThere == True:
            numTypeRoots[z] = numTypeRoots[z] + 1;
    return numTypeRoots;
```

code works though when not in module as shown here:

```
for y in range (0, numRoots):
    root = roots[y];
    rootThere = root in word;
    if rootThere == True:
        numTypeRoots[y] = numTypeRoots[y] + 1;
```

Basic program takes a list of words in from a file and then looks to see if a particular root is in the word.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: "My code doesn't work" **is not an adequate problem statement**

Comment: What is `word`? You don't need those semicolons. And `if root in word: ...` reads better.

Comment: You're going to make your programming and SO-asking life much easier if you write functions that operate entirely on parameters explicitly passed to them and provide complete examples when you run into problems. Take a look at how to write a [MCVE]

Comment: Unless whatever is returned by `createList` is _really_ special, you could replace it very easily with a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which exists to do exactly what you're doing here.  A plain old `dict` would work, too.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] and a _detailed_ description of the problem.  What code is in which file?  What are you doing, what happened, and what were you expecting to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

The function is doing `root in word` but I think what you actually want to do is `root in wordChecked`

Global variables are the devil. best to avoid them if you can help it.

Suggestion - if writing Python code that other people might look at ( hint: probably any/all code) it's a good idea to read through and follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)